# How to set the output of ^Z (Control-Z) to output the PID of the stopped process?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I start my script `bash test.sh` and then press Control-Z and get this:

```
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 bash test.sh
```

All fine. But I want that the output also has the PID.

I know I can do this `ps $(jobs -p)` afterwards to get the PID. But how it is possible that the output of Control-Z prints directly the PID?

Comment: `jobs -l` is simpler than trying to match from `ps`

Comment: As a workaround you can run it as `bash test.sh; jobs -l %%`  to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I don't *think* that's possible. That said, perhaps you can take a step back and clarify why you are hoping to do that?

Because what you *can* do is directly refer to the particular job with `%1` (or `%<n>` more generally, if you have multiple background jobs) for several built-in commands (`fg`, `bg`, `kill`, ...):

```
$ sleep 30
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 30
$ kill %1
[1]+  Terminated: 15          sleep 30
```

More details in `man bash` or here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control-Basics